# Unable to centre align main page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment

I have a WordPress main page that everything is aligned to the left. I want to move them to the center > http://www.architravel.com/destinations/.

Could you kindly explain what do i have to do to center it?

That is the code of the main page:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Home page
 *
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>

<table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td height="200" colspan="2" valign="bottom">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" valign="bottom">
        <a href="<?php get_home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/destinations_top.jpg" alt="Architravel Destinations" width="518" height="56" border="0"> <div style="clear:both;"></div></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#506DAF">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/top.jpg" width="1230" height="257" alt="top" >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" colspan="2">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="405" height="102" valign="top" >
                <a href="http://www.architeam.org/#/projects" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/architeam.jpg" alt="Architeam Projects" width="410" height="102" border="0"></a>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/planebottom.jpg" align="left" alt="top_bottom">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <a href="http://www.architeam.org/#/projects" target="_blank"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td height="50" colspan="10" valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="190" valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="25" valign="top">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/doty.jpg" width="20" height="18" alt="doty">
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                 Last Destination: &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="350" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <a href="/destinations/trips/los-angeles-las-vegas-san-francisco/" class="front">LOS ANGELES - LAS VEGAS - SAN FRANCISCO</a><br/>
            </td>
            <td width="25" valign="top">
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/doty.jpg" width="20" height="18" alt="doty">
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                Destinations Archive: &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <a href="/destinations/trips/mexico/" class="front">MEXICO</a> |
                <a href="/destinations/trips/singapore-malaysia/" class="front">SINGAPORE - MALAYSIA</a> | 
                <a href="/destinations/trips/china" class="front">CHINA</a> | 
                <a href="/destinations/trips/brazil" class="front">BRAZIL </a> | 
                <a href="/destinations/trips/zaragoza-bilbao" class="front">ZARAGOZA - BILBAO</a> | 
                <a href="/destinations/trips/japan" class="front">JAPAN</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="50" colspan="10" valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                <a href="http://www.architravel.com/archipaper/" target="_blank" title="ArchiPaper"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/archipaper.jpg" alt="ArchiPaper" width="250" height="61" border="0"></a>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" valign="center">
                <a href="http://www.architravel.com" target="_blank" title="ArchiTravel"><img src="http://www.architravel.com/destinations/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ArchiTravel_LOGO.png" alt="ArchiTravel" width="250" height="68" border="10"></a>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insure it cant be over-riden i would assign it an ID in a div and align the div.

```
<div id='table1'>
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

And then you can style it with

```
#table1{
    text-align:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`align="left"`

to:

`align="center"`

in your table.